# PostgreSQL Split word into letters

Tags: postgresql

I would like to split a text data type and CAST it as a text[].
Something like this: 'Hello world' => ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'].

More specifically the table will look something like this

```sql
SELECT some_string,
  split_into_array(some_string) AS some_array
FROM table_name
```

I'm fairly new to PostgreSQL, but I've been reading the documentation.

I wasn't able to find anything [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)
Nor was I able to find anything that seemed appropriate in the similar questions audit.

I tried this...

```sql
SELECT some_string,
    CAST(some_string AS text[]) AS res
FROM table_name;
```

But I got the error

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "I am a string"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
SQL state: 22P02
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of PostgreSQL? If it's version 14 or later, then you can use `string_to_array(some_string, NULL)`. For older versions, use `regexp_split_to_array(some_string, '.{0}')`.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding the error occured because you attempted to cast the text data straight as a `text[]`, however the issue happened because PostgreSQL thought the array literal should either begin with `'{'` or contain dimension information. Use the `regexp_split_to_array` method to convert a text data type into an array of characters, which creates the desired array format without the need for manual array literal formatting.